# Master of Research (MRes) schools in the U.S.?

Tags: masters, united-states

Are there brick-and-mortar or online schools that confer [Master of Research (MRes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Research)-type degrees in the U.S.?

Comment: Which aspects of the degree do you care about?  There are certainly master's programs in the U.S. in which one carries out research and writes a master's thesis, but I haven't heard of them getting a special designation like MRes.  Would any research-based master's program satisfy you, or are you looking for something beyond that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the term "Master of Research" used in the US.  Many master's degree programs in the US do include a significant research component (either a thesis or project) while other master's degree programs consist entirely of coursework.  In either case, the degree can be called an MS (Master of Science) or MA (Master of Arts) degree.

In programs that do include a thesis, the thesis might be 6 out of 30 credit hours in the degree program.  This is nominally 20% of the program but in practice students often spend much more than 20% of their time on the thesis.  In my experience in mathematics, 3 semesters of course work plus two semesters of work on the thesis is more typical.

Comment: My understanding of MRes degrees in the U.K. is that they consist 100% of research and no coursework. Is that true?

Comment: From what I understand, MRes degrees are not 100% research degrees but simply master's degrees with a large research component and less course work than a conventional program.  However, I don't work in the British system, so I can't provide an authoritative answer.

Comment: Research Master's degrees programmes courses in the UK must guarantee that at least 70% of the content is project based as it is "geared to those wishing to pursue a research career afterwards." http://www.prospects.ac.uk/postgraduate_qualifications_masters.htm